# How to control quadraticCurve handles position with mouse position?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

How can I control quadraticCurve handles position with mouse position without overlapping like [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/bdA9C8IwEAbgvxKyWKFoRVwqTp0FoW7qEJOTlqa5ek2qpfjfTYuKXzeEO/JwvEnHjSiBxzwtwMqMh1yi6uc97Q3zhWaNroY1NsBW7OSMtDmaABowdsy6J+urEcQqYTPvDFzYxrfBePku+ttJ6VdtMZhHUTiLoj+gtoQFJKiR/KrRUTsY/apTrvXLEKhPMp0+lNO6TUGDtKC8tOTgd9fZCUXC5jJxNIQbnjepMPfnNXyf2rAPvvgO/uxv/gePBKIYdM3j3eF2Bw==)?
I need something like this

```
onMouseMove = function(event) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(300,100);
    path.strokeColor = 'blue';
    path.fillColor = 'red';
    // path.fullySelected = true;
    path.quadraticCurveTo(event.point.x,event.point.y,300,500);

}
```

but without drawing over previous path. Is there any way to achieve dynamic quadraticCurve handles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you're creating a new `Path` item on each `onMouseMove` event without removing any previous items. If you want to only render one path item, create the path's variable out of scope, and remove it before creating a new item:

```
var path = new Path();

onMouseMove = function(event) {
    path.remove();

    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(300,100);
    path.strokeColor = 'blue';
    path.fillColor = 'red';
    // path.fullySelected = true;
    path.quadraticCurveTo(event.point.x,event.point.y,300,500);

}
```

[Here's a sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/bZDBCsIwDIZfpfTihOEm4mXiaeeBoDf1ULuIY10zs3Yq4rvbbiI6zSEk5Mufv71zLSrgCV+XYOSJh1xi7vtWEKuFObEl03BhK1cG48VOMxd9Rp2hbSDDFhx0tFqaAnUALWgzZvce8uFlJgSVAzuJ78m/A+8tv7PBYBbH4TSOf8aNISwhRYXkZEYHZWE0ZI6FUm+CIP8EoujFWKVua1AgDeSOM2RhqHO2IidhCpla6kx1D53UWLh8DT+7W+gNz78N99XD/fCBQJQd2fBku388AQ==)

Alternatively, you can move the control `handles` of the curve instead of creating a new `Path` on each event.

```
var path = new Path([300, 100], [300, 500]);
path.strokeColor = 'blue';
path.fillColor = 'red';

onMouseMove = function(event) {
   path.segments[0].handleOut = (event.point -path.segments[0].point)/1.5;
   path.segments[1].handleIn = (event.point - path.segments[1].point)/1.5;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Second solution! That's what i'm looking for! Every segment has it's own handles.
Thank you very much!